# Save in mysql from foreach

Tags: php, mysql

Hi friends sorry for my english. I have question how can I save links into mysql ?? I'm newbie in programming php. Thanks for all answer.

```php
<?php

set_time_limit(0); 
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'pass');
$db -> query("SET CHARSET utf8");
$db -> query("SET NAMES 'UTF-8' COLLATE 'utf8_polish_ci'");

$html = file_get_contents("http://www.somesite.com");
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach ($divs as $div){
     if(preg_match('/\bimgw\b/', $div->getAttribute('class'))) {
         $links = $div->getElementsByTagName('a');
         foreach($links as $link){
              $li = $link->getAttribute('href');
                $zapytanie = "SELECT * FROM `dane` WHERE link='".$li."';";
                $wynik = $db->query($zapytanie);
                $baza = mysql_fetch_assoc($wynik) ;
                if ($baza['link'] == $li)
        print ("OK Exist ".$baza['ID'].'<br>');
                else

                echo ("<br>Not exist ".$baza['ID']);

         }
     }
}

?>
```

Comment: so, when do you want to insert? when you get *`Not Exist`* message?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: mixing mysql with mysqli is not going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)**
 you're not selecting `database` while connecting to `host`, connection string will be

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'database');
```

**2)** you're mixing `mysql` with `mysqli`, it simply won't work in any scenario,
so, this line `$baza = mysql_fetch_assoc($wynik) ;` will become `$baza = mysqli_fetch_assoc($wynik) ;`

**3)** you can't do this `echo ("<br>Not exist ".$baza['ID']);` in `else` as this code will only run if it doesn't find anything from `database`, so you don't have index `$baza['ID']`, so, when your code about to hit `else` condition, then do this(replace your `else` with this code)

```
else{
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `dane`(`link`) VALUES(?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $li);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

and at the end of the `foreach`(outside the loop)

```
$stmt->close();
$db->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx for answer... I understand now what i did wrong. I put into code echo and print because i wanted see what is bad but this is wrong way.
I read your post and used your advice but is not work ;(

```php
<?php

set_time_limit(0); 
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'test');
$db -> query("SET CHARSET utf8");
$db -> query("SET NAMES 'UTF-8' COLLATE 'utf8_polish_ci'");

$html = file_get_contents("http://somesite.com");
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach ($divs as $div){
     if(preg_match('/\bimgw\b/', $div->getAttribute('class'))) {
         $links = $div->getElementsByTagName('a');
         foreach($links as $link){
              $li = $link->getAttribute('href');
                $zapytanie = "SELECT * FROM `dane` WHERE link='".$li."';";
                $wynik = $db->query($zapytanie);
                $baza = mysqli_fetch_assoc($wynik) ;
                if ($baza['link'] == $li)
        print ('OK Exist <br>');
                else
                {
                $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `test`.`dane` (`link`) VALUES (?);");
                $stmt->bind_param("s", $li);
                $stmt->execute();
                }

           $stmt->close();
           $db->close();
         }
     }
}







?>
```

Comment: put, `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top and check what error does this show, moreover, try to `echo $li;` to view what you got there.

Comment: Thx friend I should put $stmt into my if else clause and work ;)

Comment: `$stmt->close(); $db->close();` put these two lines just outside the very next closing bracket `}`